# Open chromium from bash script using crontab

Tags: shell-script, chrome

I'm trying to open Chromium from a bash script. This script can be executed in any moment / at the moment scheduled in crontab. I'm using Debian 9.

This script kills Chromium if the script is executed with the parameter `off`, and opens it if the parameter is `on`.

Executing the script from the terminal manually works, but using **crontab** / using PHP `shell_exec()` function as the same user used in the terminal won't work.

This is the bash script. The log is empty. Chromium won't open. ¿Any suggestion?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 'off' ]
then
echo "Chromium OFF"
pkill -x -15 chromium
else
echo "Chromium ON"
chromium http://localhost/shopCaseCodeigniter/selectSlideshowForScreen/1 --kiosk --password-store=basic > /home/miguel/Scripts/logs/chromium.log 2>&1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to add `export DISPLAY=:0` to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 'off' ]
then
echo "Chromium OFF"
pkill -x -15 chromium
else
echo "Chromium ON"
export DISPLAY=:0
chromium http://localhost/shopCaseCodeigniter/selectSlideshowForScreen/1 --kiosk --password-store=basic > /home/miguel/Scripts/logs/chromium.log 2>&1
fi
```